# Want to calculate 18 digits but will only calculate to 6? Using long double but still won't work

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, long-double

I've written a program to estimate pi using the Gregory Leibniz formula, however, it will not calculate to 18 decimal points.  It will only calculate up to 5 decimal points. Any suggestions?

Comment: `float` and `double` on most platforms can't represent numbers to 18 decimal points. The typical precision for `double` is 15 digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
cout.precision(50);
```

To increase the precision of the printed output. Here 50 is the number of decimal digits in your output.

Comment: This will only increase numbers to be printed on output, the real precision depends on the type being used.

Comment: @Mac Of course, remember what LưuVĩnhPhúc has told you. You may get a precision printed which is limited by the precision of the data type you're using. So with double, you may get up to 16 digits, not more. If you want more, use higher precision libraries, which are relatively expensive to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [default *printing* precision for `printf` is 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

> Precision specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the decimal point character. The default precision is 6

Similarly when `std::cout` was introduced into C++ the same default value was used

> Manages the precision (i.e. how many digits are generated) of floating point output performed by `std::num_put::do_put`.
>
> 1. Returns the current precision.
> 2. Sets the precision to the given one. Returns the previous precision.
>
> The default precision, as established by `std::basic_ios::init`, is 6.
>
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision

Therefore regardless of how precise the type is, **only 6 fractional digits will be printed out**. To get more digits you'll need to use [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) or [`std::cout.precision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision)

However calling `std::cout.precision` only affects the number of decimal digits *in the output*, **not** the number's *real precision*. Any digits over that type's precision would be just **garbage**

Most modern systems use IEEE-754 where `float` is [single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) with 23 bits of mantissa and `double` maps to [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) with 52 bits of mantissa. As a result they're accurate to ~6-7 digits and ~15-16 decimal digits respectively. That means they **can't represent numbers to *18 decimal points* as you expected**

On some platforms there may be some [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) types so you'll be able to store numbers more precisely. For example `long double` on most compilers on x86 has 64 bits of precision and can represent ~18 significant digits, but it's **not** 18 digits after the decimal point. Higher precision can be obtained with [quadruple-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) on some compilers. To achieve even more precision, the only way is to use a [big number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library or write one for your own.